# Regularity of matrix with coefficients from GF$(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, prime-numbers

I have matrix $A$ (its size is $n \times n$) with coefficients from GF($p$), where $p$ is prime. How can be proven that this matrix has all lines linearly independent iff det$(A)\neq 0 $(mod $p$). I am trying to solve this but I am not sure if it is true.

Thanks for every advice or reference to literature.

Comment: **Exactly** in the same way as you did (I hope) with matrices over $\;\Bbb R\;$ or over $\;\Bbb C\;$

Comment: There is no need to write "(mod $p$)" for $\det(A)$, as you are performing arithmetic operations over $GF(p)$ but not doing modulo arithmetic over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Reduce your matrix by rows until you reach echelon form. In this case, we know $\,\det A\,$ is simply the product of the elements on the main diagonal, which is zero iff no row became all zeros iff the matrix is regular.

This is exactly the same argument over any field or even integral domain.

Comment: Thanks, with your anwer it is clear to me.